# How to get the new thread info for onCreate() and keep thread-safety?

Tags: android, thread-safety

Experts,

I have a very long code inside onCrate() in a activity. At the beginning of the long code, I need to judge if the net is bad, if yes, return and skip the remaining code.

I understand I cannot judge the net in UI thread, so I need to use AsyncTask, or Handler&Runnable.

But all tutorial I learned is get the net bad or ok status in a new thread and pass to onPostExecute(AsyncTask) or handleMessage(Handler), then update UI or do something in onPostExecute(AsyncTask) or handleMessage(Handler), for they are in UI thread.

Above is not what I need, what I need is bring the net bad or ok info to onCreate() method, so I can know if I should continue run the remaining code inside onCreate() or not.

(Note that before onCreate() got net info from new thread(takes time), need to avoid execute the remaining code)

But I don't know how to do? Could you help please? Thanks in advance.

(Also if I need to pass param inside onCreate() to the new Runnable, how to do?)

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if net is bad then return;

        // more than 1 thousand other codes...

    } 
}
```

Handler example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.num) {
           case 1: show net is ok in a UI textview
           case 2: show net is bad
           (but how to pass the msg.num to inside onCreate()?)
        }
    } 
};

Runnable newTread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // judge net statements
        msg.obj = num;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check internet in onResume() method, and doing things after that。 you said you will return onCreate when case 2 , maybe you should use this.finish() in case2.

Comment: right, but what I more interesting is communication between onCreate() and new thread. The code is just an example, I may need a lot of other info, other judgement between them in the real coding.

Comment: If you just want to finish this activity after all judgement,I think maybe there is a way to achieve this . but if you want more than just finish , I'm afraid that , because in your opinion , onCreate must wait for the judgement, Doesn't it mean they are in the "same" thread?

Comment: that is exactly my concern!   I really need same thread, how come Android force me to use different thread (like check a URL)? What should I do in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say, I personal think my question is typical and useful practice, yet no answer.

I also believe I post my question clear enough.

After a few days' study, I found Callable interface should be the right answer, I can define a boolean return value to speak for the net status, also the get() method guarantee thread-safe.

However, I search the whole google and android APIs, cannot find a Callable example for android.

Really cannot understand why this question treated coldly...